# What is the performance difference between booting Ubuntu from a USB v2 and USB v3?

Tags: boot, usb, performance

I like the idea of booting from a usb drive.  I probably have 50 USB 2.0 drives of various sizes, but I only have 2 USB 3.0 drives currently.

If I boot from a USB 3.0, will the increased read/write speeds make a noticeable difference in performance?

Comment: I doubt that you can use USB 3.0 speeds without USB 3.0 drivers booted.

Comment: Impossible to answer with the current information. Brand and size of the pendrive matters (larger size pendrives are slower ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind Your comment makes me think that booting from a usb 3.0 drive **could increase performance** if I had a high quality usb 3.0 drive of a certain size vs a certain usb 2.0 drive. 

So I guess what I am asking is, in optimum hardware conditions, if I booted from a usb 3.0 drive would my computer ** theoretically** have increased performance than if I booted from a usb 2.0.  I understand that there are different pendrive brands and storage sizes that could affect the outcome.

Comment: I do not believe you will see a difference when booting (only in usage **after** booting) but feel free to prove me wrong (you are the one with the pendrives ;) )

Answer (score 2):

For USB 3.0 to boot, 3 things must work:

It must support booting by showing itself as a bootable device, most USB3.0 drives can do this.

The BIOS must support USB 3.0 booting.  Most PC's made in the last year should support booting from USB 3.0

The OS must also support a USB 3.0 boot by having the right device drivers and must be willing to boot a removable drive. For Linux, this is no problem.  The xhci module, which is needed for USB 3.0 is included in recent kernels.

That being said, I agree with what Rinzwind stated in his comment.  I installed Ubuntu 13.04 from a 16GB USB 2.0 Flash Drive, and from a 16GB USB 3.0 Flash Drive, both drives are made by Imitation.

Installation took the same amount of time ± 10 seconds.  So no performance difference between booting Ubuntu from either a USB 2 or 3.

Now if you create a persistent USB, and run Ubuntu from that, it may make a difference that way, but I can't verify since I didn't test.